CavalCade -> motorcade
I have read this questio What is the etymology of "-cade" as in motorcade or cavalcade?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorcade says
The term motorcade was coined by Lyle Abbot (in 1912 or 1913 when he was automobile editor of the Arizona Republican), and is formed after cavalcade, playing off of the last syllable in that word. The original suffix in cavalcade is actually "-ade", and there is no "-cade" in either French or Latin.
but where does the C in cade come from? In horserelated words like cavalry and cavalier, caval ends in an l with no c before the suffic. Why isn't it cavalade if the Wikipedia article about the etymology of motorcade is correct?

Answers to the question to which you link does in fact explain the 'c'.

@Greybeard No it doesn't. Please quote something that supports your claim.

If you take the trouble to read all the way down the linked question to James K's answer you might be lucky enough to find this: The latin verb ending -icare forms verbs from nouns. So from the (late, vulgar) latin word caballus one get caballicare directly translated that means "to 'horse'", which is how a late latin speaker would say "to ride a horse"
